# Return type depending on parameter type (e.g. Await.ready()) does not work as expected

Tags: scala, types, path-dependent-type

Scala `Await.ready()` method is defined like this:

```
def ready[T](awaitable: Awaitable[T], atMost: Duration): awaitable.type = ...
```

That is, the return type is a path-dependent type of `awaitable` parameter. I thought that (and IntelliJ IDEA agreed with me) this means that if I pass `Future` to the function, it should return `Future` of the same type, and indeed, it does work in simple cases:

```
val f: Future[Int] = Future { 10 }
val ft: Future[Int] = Await.ready(f, ???)
```

This code compiles, that is, `Await.ready()` here really returns `Future[Int]`. However, the following does **not** work:

```
val f: Future[Int] = Future { 10 }
val ft: Future[Int] = Await.ready(f.map(identity), ???)
```

It fails with this error:

```
[error] /Users/netvl/dev/work/sandbox/src/main/scala/circuit/actors/Example.scala:53: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : awaitable.type (with underlying type scala.concurrent.Awaitable[Int])
[error]  required: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
[error]       val ft: Future[Int] = Await.ready(f.map(identity), ???)
[error]                                        ^
```

Why does it happen? `f.map(identity)` returns `Future[Int]`, so I thought that calling methods on the future which return another future should work too. The only thing to fix this (aside from rewriting) seems to be `asInstanceOf[Future[Int]]` call, type ascriptions do not work.

BTW, as a small side question, how `variable.type` syntax is properly called? I know it is related to path-dependent types, but I couldn't find its exact name or description and had a hard time googling for it.

I'm using Scala 2.10.4.

Comment: `variable.type` is called "self type"

Comment: Actually no, this is called a "singleton type"

Comment: @wedens, really? I thought self type is `this: A with B with C =>` inside class declaration.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles, indeed, it is. Googling for "singleton type" was very fruitful, though I still couldn't find the answer on the main question.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev `this: A with B with C =>` called "self type annotations". and it's actually related to "self type".

Comment: @wedens, well, "self" usually means "this class", so, I guess, `this.type` can be called a "self type", but `someArbitraryVar.type` cannot, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scala version would be helpful here. With Scala 2.11.1 it works perfectly fine:

```
scala> val f: Future[Int] = Future(10)
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@68d0db31

scala> val ft: Future[Int] = Await.ready(f.map(identity), 1.second)
ft: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@68d0db31
```

Comment: The problem is with the second snippet (the one with `f.map(identity)`, not the first one

Comment: @drexin, when passing future alone into the `ready` call, it works fine. It's the method call what gives problems. And yes, I'm using Scala 2.10.4, I should've mentioned that.

Comment: I can confirm that the second snippet works correctly in 2.11 but not in 2.10.4 - this is the right answer, only the example is wrong.

Comment: Nice, this would indicate that it really was a compiler bug. I suspected it was.

Comment: Sorry, pasted the wrong snippet. Thanks for correcting it!